# How to append fqbn in Plone 4 rss

Tags: plone

need to dealing with a stupid rss reader that it just render right with links that included fqdn any link start with ../ or / will treat as local file and return .

Is that possible mod the plone 4 rss?

Comment: Where does Plone generate relative links for RSS? Example?

Comment: Any idea how to change default rss output from relate to absolute path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSS feed passes content body text HTML as is:

https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/rss_template.pt#L61

Your body text content has relative links.

Solutions

- Use Link by UID feature of TinyMCE editor (affects only new content)
- Create a a custom RSS view which will rewrite links to absolute URLs. An example which could be applied for this problem http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc/html.html?highlight=lxml#rewriting-relative-links

Comment: Thanks... the first UID solution not work with 4.2... will dig in the 2nd solution... seems petty hard... don't know where the files to put.

Comment: Both solutions work. If it doesn't work please specify how it doesn't work.

Comment: the RSS return <p><img class="image-inline" src="resolveuid/fe40f347868aee9a5fdcf2992e8e0725" /></p> but I want something <img src="http://www.domain.com/images/xxxx.png">

Comment: item.getText() should automatically translate resolveuid URLs to full URLs. AFAIK I can try to confirm this tomorrow with my own site.

Comment: It *should* give you full URLs as confirmed in IRC: <davisagli> moo-_-: it'll happen during getText if your field stores as text/html and outputs as text/x-html-safe, which is configurable per field... but there might be some issue here

Comment: Do you see resolveuids correctly as absolute link when you try to view the pages normally?

Comment: It show <img class="image-inline" src="resolveuid/fe40f347868aee9a5fdcf2992e8e0725" /> in normal view Plone 4.2.0.1 (4206)

Comment: Where I can set the output to text/x-html-safe ?

Comment: It is the default. Unless you have disabled safe HTML transformation e.g. to allow <script> tags and such in content it should kick in automatically. More info http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms/wysiwyg.html?highlight=safe%20html#rich-text-transformations

Comment: Thanks @nikko I rebuild my site and copy paste the data too... and thx so much to confirm this work.